# Iframe abrir los links de un iframe en otra pestaña

Tags: iframe

Tengo un iframe que visualiza otra web, el problema es que toda accion que haga dentro del iframe solo sucede en el iframe y nunca sale de ahi, hay alguna manera de cuando clickeas en algun enlace se abra este en una nueva pestaña y no se haga todo desde dentro del iframe??, porque cuando clickeas en alguna red social o whatsapp de contacto no redirecciona debido a que estas webs tienen bloqueados los iframes

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.